# iPhone 6 started making random faint pinging sounds

Tags: iphone, ios

My iPhone 6 (iOS 10.3.2) recently started making faint random pinging sounds. This happens several times every few minutes and doesn't appear related to anything, as far as I can tell.  I performed a hard restart but it had no effect. None of my notifications were set to sound only and the pinging sound is faint, having a volume lower than my notifications. Does anyone have a clue about why this is happening?

Comment: Does the pinging is from the horn or the iphone hardware?

Comment: The pinging comes from speaker I'm pretty sure.

Comment: How much disk do you leave? if the disk is almost full maybe it will get this issue.

Comment: Good thought but I have 28 GB free. Almost half. So I don't think its storage problem.